# Which Gen 5 Pokemon have viable Transfer moves when transferred to Sun/Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-fifth-generation

I've been looking everywhere for some kind of list like this, but so far no luck. Now that the Pokemon Bank updates have rolled out, I've started eyeing previous generations (V for now) that can still transfer all the way up to Sun/Moon.

I know as generations change, some movepools change, and earlier generation Pokemon can be transferred up a Gen with the old moves intact.

Looking back at older generations, what are some good Pokemon/move combos I should keep an eye out for for transferring into the current generation? I know there was a lot of talk of Machamp/Fissure from the Gen I games (hidden abilities took care of that though) - any others to keep in mind besides Gen I?

Comment: For example, here's some Gen 1 combos I found online to look for:  
Clefairy - Double-Edge, 
Hitmonlee - Double-Edge,    
Zapdos - Reflect,  
Chansey - Bide/Tri-Attack

Comment: This is a very broad question requiring extensive research on 6 generations worth of Pokemon. You should consider restricting this to a single generation's game (such as Gen 5, as you mention you are playing Black 2)

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: This also highly depends on the format you intend to play. VGC17, for instance, only allows Alola-bred or Alola-caught Pokemon, so any moves that cannot be passed on through breeding are irrelevant to that format anyway. Also the term "viable" is generally rather opinion-based.

Comment: I'm coming at this as a general breeder. As I'm casually playing through a previous gen game, just an idea of what to keep an eye out for when it comes to finishing and transferring Pokemon to the bank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer:**
Pokemon who have used the Move Tutor for viable moves.

**Long Answer**:
There are two types of moves that often become inaccessible in new Generations, and therefore are useful for transferring. I've tried to summarize the specific moves to look for.

### 1 - Old Move Tutor Moves

The first thing to look for is Pokemon with [Move Tutor](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Move_Tutor#Sun_and_Moon) moves.

A specific example I know of is [Gengar](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Gengar_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), which can be tutored [Icy Wind](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Icy_Wind_(move)) in Gen V or Gen VI (ORAS), but cannot get access to it in Gen VII (SM). This also happens in the case of [Azumarill](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Azumarill_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) with [Knock Off](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Knock_Off_(move)).

Popular Gen V move tutor moves include Fire Punch, Thunder Punch, Ice Punch, Iron Head, Icy Wind, Dragon Pulse, Knock Off, Drain Punch, Tailwind, Stealth Rock, Skill Swap. This is not the complete list of Gen V move tutor moves, but ones I recall as being competitive. I had originally included Roost, but it is now a TM instead. Dark Pulse became a TM again in Gen VI.

### 2 - Obsolete TM

The second type of move to look for are TMs which are no longer TMs, such as [Pluck](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pluck_(move)), which was TM88 in Gen V. Both [Swanna](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Swanna_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) and [Togekiss](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Togekiss_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) can learn Pluck from TM in Gen V, and have no access to it in Gen VII.

There aren't many moves that lost TM status, but some may have niche use. Pluck, Ally Switch, Retaliate, Dig, and Telekinesis all were TMs in Gen V, and are not in Gen VII. Defog is another popular move from an HM in Gen IV that still sees use in Gen VII competitive formats.

### Bonus - Breeding From Previous Generation

This really isn't going to be comprehensive, as [Egg Moves](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Egg_Move) are specific to the the Pokemon, and there isn't a master list to reference. Anyways, some moves can be bred on, but the Pokemon required for breeding aren't in the current generation.

Extra fun is that sometimes [Chain Breeding](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Chain_breeding) isn't enough, and you need to set *that* up in the previous generation to get the move you want. And if you checked that link, you'll notice that Bulbapedia does not have a comprehensive list for me to cite, but just two examples.

For example [Exeggcute](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Exeggcute_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#By_breeding) has [Power Swap](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Power_Swap_(move)) as an egg move, you just need to breed with [Seedot](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Seedot_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) or [Tangela](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Tangela_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) (who actually needs it from Seedot anyways), who aren't native to Sun or Moon and have to be transferred from a previous generation. Seedot doesn't even learn Power Swap, but needs to get it from Espeon, which you can get in Gen VII.

If you need all cases of where this method is applicable you'll likely need to crawl Bulbapedia yourself. My recommendation is to look for the Pokemon you want to use, and then backtrack all of the moves that you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I often look to Bulbapedia for egg moves when breeding and notice there's usually at least one that has to be chain bred from a previous generation. I thought there would be a more comprehensive list of moves like this, but wasn't having any luck to date finding one.

Comment: @Charasan YI had forgotten about that type of breeding, I'll add some info on it to the answer, but you're right, it doesn't seemed to be summarized anywhere

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Like you said, I thought a list like this would already exist as thorough as the community is, but c'est la vie. This is a good starting point, though, going forward. Thanks.